# React Typescript Mui `onBlur` firing every change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, blur, onblur, mui

I am writing a front-end app in Typescript and React and am using MUI. I have the following code for a form:

```
<TextField
  label="Password"
  value={this.state.password}
  placeholder="Choose a password"
  type="password"
  onChange={(event: any) => this.setState({
    password: event.target.value
  })}
  onBlur={console.log('here')}
  error={this.state.passwordError}
/>
```

With this code, every time I click a key, `onBlur` gets fired. Isn't it only supposed to fire when I leave the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be helpful to see the `onblur` function. It doesn't look like you want to pass anything to it, so simply changing the line `onBlur={this.onblur()}` to `onBlur={this.onblur}` should do the trick.

However, if your function looks like this

```
onblur() {
...
}
```

then you should bind the context to it ('this'). Instead, I'd suggest going for

```
onblur = event => {
...
}
```

which will have the context already binded.

Comment: I apologize. Right now I am trying to do anything. I was trying it with a console log: `onBlur={console.log('here')}, Does that change anything?

Comment: The arrow worked! Why does doing that make it work?

Comment: Technically, you need an arrow function for the `onClick` to call. You were using `this.onblur()` which isn't an arrow function and therefore should be replaced with `() => this.onblur()` if you want to keep the `()`. The problem with this is that it will generate an anonymous function everytime your component re-renders - which is more expensive on the performance, I believe. Instead you want to define one at the component level and pass it like you would pass a variable `this.onblur`. In that case, your `onblur` means `(event) => onblur()` which is an arrow function essentially.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.